# Can i get mouse input from an Xbox UWP app

Tags: input, uwp, operating-system, mouse, xbox

I want to add to an xbox remote desktop/remote gaming app mouse support but i dont know if the OS or app captures it.

I have seen that people cant get it to work but in Minecraft it shows the mouse and all that so maybe asking here would help me.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to enable the mouse input mode in an application running on Xbox? If it is, you could try [Application.RequiresPointerMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requirespointermode?view=winrt-22621)

Comment: I belive that the "Aplication.RequiresPointerMode" emulates the mouse pointer but I don't want that I want to use the physical mouse for input but idk if or how I can make that work

Answer (score 0):

Only specific UWP on Xbox applications are enabled to use mouse (such as Minecraft and the Xbox Shell). Mouse support is not available for most UWP applications on Xbox.

Comment: Yeah but why tho wouldnt making it open be more profitabile? Also fortnite and Warzone use the mouse. So there is a way but idk what to do